# How can I access a file inside the Pods?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods, nsbundle

I have a project that uses Cocoapods. It includes some third-party libraries I have been using. But, as per the instruction by a developer, I had to sub-class one of them. The original class used to access a file "XYZ.bundle" in the "Pods" section of the project. But when I am trying to access the same from the sub-class, it returns nil now (in the original file also it is now returning nil when I am using this sub-classed item).

```
NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("XYZ", ofType: "bundle")
```

returns nil.

So, how can I access the bundle file in the Pods of a project?

Comment: Can you post your Podfile as well?

Comment: make sure you add the bundle in the build phases

Comment: I am sorry that I can't share the file at the moment. :/

I tried adding it in the Build Phases, but the bundle doesn't show up in the list to add.